# When I run my project so it will showing the following error(parse error),i created a register page and want to send data in data base "wamp server"

Tags: php, database

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in
>   C:\wamp\www\pro\sagarnow\register.php on line 21

Comment: Can we see your code? its broke is because somewhere before line 21 there is a syntax error in your `if` condition.

Comment: <?php
 else
 {
  echo"not inserted";
 }
?>it is from line 20 to 25 code and i think there is no error in this line when i hide this code so  it will give error at the last in </html> this tag  @LawrenceCherone i think its not a code error its special error in wamp server